# Replace output console in Xcode

Tags: xcode

Is there a way to replace the output console in Xcode or alternatively do highlighting/filtering?

Comment: The Xcode console is only really intended for testing/debugging etc - what are you trying to achieve, exactly ?

Comment: Clearer output during debugging by filtering or highlighting certain fields or lines

Comment: Great question. The Xcode standard debugger is so backwards. I want colors, highlighting, line wrapping. It's a neglected area.

Comment: There are Xcode plugins that allow some of this, at least.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eventually did [this](http://objcolumnist.com/2009/12/19/redirecting-nslog-to-a-log-file/).

Redirected to a file and ran `tail` on it